# php exec() return error when calling external program (postmap)

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to update the postfix databases inside a php code (Apache linux based server)

I tried to use the shell_exec() and exec() command like this:

```php
$out =shell_exec('postmap /etc/postfix/virtual; echo $?');
var_dump($out);
```

While `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` works in the command line, I'm have a 1 error code when calling it like this inside my php and it does nothing.
`/etc/postfix/virtual` is in chmod 666 and /usr/sbin/postmap `-rwxr-xr-x`
"Of course" it works when I'm calling the php as a cli.

Other programs like (ls or echo) works.
Do you have any idea why it doesn't works?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
1. To check where the problem exactly come from (I was guessing it was a privilege problem), I redirected STDERR to STDOUT so I can debug clearly the code.

`exec('postmap /etc/postfix/virtual 2>&1',$output);`

Then I learned that postmap is looking for `/etc/postfix/virtual.db` and not `/etc/postfix/virtual` and had no right to write.
Setting the file chmod as 666 fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you aware that you're disabling security and any user in your machine can now mess with Postfix configuration?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, this was just a resolution example and did not implemented it in my live environment. Giving the rights only to apache would be better but at the end I stopped using this file and I now use an SQL method where I don't have to edit any server file